# Two IE windows being opened by VBScript, but should only be one

Tags: internet-explorer, object, vbscript

I have a VBScript that pings some server and outputs results (full code in this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kenUXybK)). Part of the script shows an IE window with a 'Please Wait' message in, but for some reason two IE windows are opened (and populated as I wish by the below code), yet only one is closed when I `Quit` at the end of the script.

Here is the function that is causing me troubles. It seems that the first line (`objExplorer.Navigate`) is opening a window as requested, but before that `Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` is also opening a window.

Does anybody know how I can stop this happening? Thanks.

```
' Display the progress box
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

display_progress(objExplorer)
main() ' Do stuff, see Pastebin for full code
close_progress(objExplorer)
output_results() ' Show user the results, see Pastebin for full code

Private Function display_progress(objExplorer)

    objExplorer.Navigate "about:blank"
    objExplorer.ToolBar = 0
    objExplorer.StatusBar = 0
    objExplorer.Left = 600
    objExplorer.Top = 374
    objExplorer.Width = 400
    objExplorer.Height = 152
    objExplorer.Visible = 1

    Dim strText, strButton

    strText = "<div id=""text""><p>Please wait, servers are being pinged.</p><p>Results will be displayed as soon as they are ready.</p></div>"
    strButton = "<div id=""buttons""><input type=""button"" name=""submit"" value=""Cancel"" onclick=""window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();"" /><div class=""clear""></div></div>"

    objExplorer.Document.Body.Style.Font = "11pt 'Halvetica'"
    objExplorer.Document.Body.Style.Cursor = "wait"
    objExplorer.Document.Title = "Server ping script"
    objExplorer.Document.Body.InnerHTML = strStyle & strText & strButton    

End Function

Private Function close_progress(objExplorer)

    objExplorer.Document.Body.Style.Cursor = "default"
    objExplorer.Quit

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

David, can you also include the following statement before 'wscript.quit' (line 14) in your code and see?

```
Set objexplorer = nothing
```

Also I saw that in your function 'force_cscript', you have used an object objshell and then used 'wscript.quit'. If you create an object, take care that you set it to nothing or null value before exiting the script. So in the function 'force_cscript', include the below statement before 'wscript.quit'.

```
Set objshell = nothing
```

If you do not do this, the object will keep running in the background. Every time you run the script, your computer will become slower n slower bcos your objects will be still active in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the advise regarding `objShell`, I forgot to add that. As for `Set objExplorer = nothing` though, I do this through the function `close_progress()`, which is run just before I exit the script. I tried your suggestion just in case, but sadly the results are still the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why your `force_cScript` function is called inside `For..Next` into `Main` sub? 
This function just restart the script if it not started with `CScript.exe` but it's 
quite enough to call it only once at the beginning and also **before** creation of IE object.

```
Call force_cScript()
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'...
```